# Round-tripping Ivy's XML files (">" unescaped in attribute values)

Tags: xml, ivy

Apache Ivy's XML serialization code does not escape `>` to `&gt;` inside of attribute values. This does not stop its content from being well-formed -- [the relevant standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax) only requires this escaping to be done in the context of the sequence `]]>`.

However, when trying to perform programmatic edits to an Ivy descriptor, this readability enhancement (which it is, given as `->` is often found inside conf specifiers) is difficult to safely round-trip.

Short of using Ivy's own libraries for this task rather than generic XML DOM tooling, what options are available? I'm flexible with respect to choice-of-language.

Comment: By "perform programmatic edits" you're presumably saying you want to modify the XML without properly parsing it. That's always a short cut to disaster.

Comment: @MichaelKay I absolutely **do** want to properly parse it. The problem is writing out the parsed DOM tree, or list of SAX events, or whatever after it's been modified without having unnecessary diffs from the library's serialization escaping `>` characters unnecessarily. If I wanted to do this the dirty, awful way, I wouldn't have had any reason to ask a question here.

Comment: OK, understood. A transformation that retains the quirks of the serialized representation is very hard to achieve. If possible use a logical diff rather than a lexical diff for comparing files. (Not always possible e.g. with version control systems.)

Comment: @MichaelKay Yup. I was hoping for a pointer to a library with a pluggable emitter design -- if I can override the entity escaping code to do only what the standard documents require and nothing more (as opposed to always escaping `>` regardless of whether in the corner case where it's mandatory, which appears to be the common approach), that would be beautiful... because modifying a source file tracked in revision control and frequently modified by humans (who can more easily work with the restrictively-serialized version) is exactly the point.

Comment: You could consider putting the file through an XML canonicalizer before storing it. Any diffs in the canonicalized form represent real logical differences.

Comment: @MichaelKay ...I'd already be using c14n form if it weren't an annoyance to my users. However, Ivy descriptors, by their nature, are frequently read and edited by humans, and `conf="foo->bar"` is considerably easier to read and write than `conf="foo-&gt;bar"`. Worse, if we put it into c14n form, the next pass through an Ivy resolver would just put it back, so we'd have competing delta sets.

Comment: Your two objectives of allowing humans to edit the XML and of automating the diffs to include only significant changes can only be reconciled, I think, if the versions you compare have insignificant differences removed first. There are of course tools like DeltaXML that give you significant differences only, but whether such tools can be integrated into your processing pipeline is something only you can judge.